# Sometimes a number appears after the correct amount of numbers is displayed

Tags: java, android

I have an app that displays a random number 5 times, every 472 ms. Every thing works except, sometimes, seemingly random, a 6th number appears for less than 472 ms and I can't figure out why. I have my count set to 6 so that the 6th number doesn't appear and clears the screen.

My Java:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import io.reactivex.Observable;
import io.reactivex.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
@SuppressLint("CheckResult")
public void display_numbers(View view) {
    final List<Integer> randomNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
    Observable.intervalRange(0, 6, 2000, 472, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .map(aLong -> {
                int previous = randomNumbers.size() > 0 ? randomNumbers.get(
                        randomNumbers.size() - 1) : -1;
                int randomNumber = generateRandomNumber();
                while (randomNumber == previous) randomNumber = 
generateRandomNumber();
                randomNumbers.add(randomNumber);
                return randomNumber;
            })
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(integer -> {
                TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                tv.setText(String.valueOf(integer));
            }, error -> {}, () -> {
                TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                tv.setText("");
            });
}
private int generateRandomNumber() {
        Random r = new Random();
        int minNumber = 1;
        int maxNumber = 9;
        return r.nextInt((maxNumber - minNumber) + 1) + minNumber;
}
    }
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by "_I have my count set to 6 but this is so it clears the 6th number so only five appears and when the 6th would appear it would clear the screen._" Could you elaborate that? Because the [io.reactivex.Observable.intervalRange](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#intervalRange-long-long-long-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) method is inclusive on both sides. So `[0,6]` would run 6 times instead of 5 times. So it will display all 6 of them in `textView1` as well as add all 6 of them to the `randomNumbers` list.

Comment: So if I only had 5 as my count, the fifth number wouldn't be displayed because the last number is blank so that the screen clears. Therefore, I had to set the count to 6 to display five numbers.